# How does Gutenberg(org) determine scraping?

Tags: curl, wget

I was attempting to download "Moby Dick" from their website to determine a word frequency test using wget w/an adjusted and proper User-Agent string, and yet they're still able to determine I'm using wget and blocked me. How are they able to do this? I tried it from multiple IP addresses, some of which were AWS VPSs, and others from normal home ISP connections. I can fire up Chrome and get the content w/o any issues, but this process piqued my curiosity. I also checked my own web server's access.log file (to test the User-Agent string) and it was as expected.

Does additional info. leak from wget connections/transfers?

Here's the link:

```
http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm
```

Comment: It's probably hard to say without access to their source code. A regular browser does a lot of things apart from setting a fancy user agent string: it sends a preferred language, it accepts cookies, it downloads images, it executes JavaScript, it parses CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [Terms of Use](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Terms_of_Use):

> This website is intended for human users only. Any perceived use of
>   automated tools to access this website will result in a temporary or
>   permanent block of your IP address.
>
> If you want to download many books (i.e., more than ~100 per day) manually or using an automated download software, download them from
>   one of our mirrors, not from the main site. See the [list of PG
>   mirrors](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Information_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages) and the [roboting guidelines](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Information_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages).

Following the last link shows some examples:

```
wget -w 2 -m -H "http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=html"
```

As you can see, they have a special URL location for bots.

Comment: Conceptually though, it's still confusing because I'm only making one request and there're no redirect that's returned from the response headers. This would mean that a cookie would never be read. So it's confusing how they'd use session info. from a cookie to determine if I'm a bot.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, there're many techniques and there's just no way to know which one they're using (I've just tweaked my personal site's contact form to reject messages where the field "Country" contains an email address because I was getting a ton of such requests).

Comment: BTW, when I load `http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm` in my browser I'm actually redirected to `http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701?msg=welcome_stranger`.

Comment: You're right Alvaro ... thank you so much! I just did what you said programmatically and it worked. You the man, much respect!

Answer (score 1):

They set a `session_id` cookie. If the request does not include that cookie, any request to a specific format of a book gets redirected to the book's top page, for example to `http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701?msg=welcome_stranger`.

Once you have a session ID cookie from Project Gutenberg you can download the book in any format.

Comment: Conceptually though, it's still confusing because I'm only making one request and there're no redirect that's returned from the response headers. This would mean that a cookie would never be read. So it's confusing how they'd use session info. from a cookie to determine if I'm a bot.

I guess in summary, I'm just not seeing a redirect.

Comment: @CharlesSaag: But what do you get when you `curl http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm`?

Comment: Thanks AlexP, I'm sure if I tried CURL it'd show me the redirect. I was able to resolve this earlier using the answer above. You and Alvaro nailed it. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.